# macOS randomly says Exchange password is needed but actually isn't

Tags: macos, keychain, exchange

I know there have been bugs that cause macOS (or the Mail app) to ask for the Exchange password repeatedly, but this is different from those.  The issue I'm having is that I receive a notification for the Exchange password and can click the notification's Continue button to make it display the Internet Accounts window but it never actually prompts me to enter a password.  When I view the entry for the Exchange account in Keychain Access, what it has is correct.  I have deleted the account entirely and re-added it to no avail, and I've also replaced the Keychain entry with an app-specific password to make sure that MFA wasn't interfering somehow.  I still receive the notifications.  Nothing is actually broken that I can find (I still receive mail and calendar events without any issues), so I'm fairly certain this is just an annoyance/cosmetic bug.  Has anyone got any ideas what could be the cause for this and how to resolve it?

I'm on a MacBook Pro (14-inch, 2021) with an Apple M1 Pro running macOS 12.1 (21C52).

Comment: I have a similar issue with an Office365 account. If at any point, the server doesn't respond properly, then it asks for the password again. I avoid this like the plague, because once a password is entered it is rejected by Outlook & you have to reset it online. This is entirely an Office bug. I've spoken to tech support about it & "there's nothing they can do." The trick is to wait it out. If it doesn't reset by just setting all accounts online again, then quit & relaunch Mail will usually shake it out.

Comment: @Tetsujin Same. It does correlate to connection issues on the far/remote side but it seems strange that it displays a password prompt (or rather a notification about a password failure but NOT an actual password prompt) rather than a connection timeout or other error to signify a connectivity problem, not an authentication problem.

Comment: I get a floating notification, with continue or ignore. Ignore is OK, continue precedes the nightmare & pops a password entry dialog in Mail [nothing you enter in this will get you back in again, wrong password says wrong password, correct password says 'error'; can't remember the wording]. Last time I accidentally hit continue was when I discovered the hoop-jumping extreme. Without responding to the password prompt, disable the account, quit, launch, re-enable, message gone, thankfully.

Comment: @Tetsujin That’s not the same as my issue, then.  Like I said in the original post, I get a notification and clicking continue displays the Internet Accounts window but that’s it - no box to actually enter a password. And nothing stops working, so it’s like it’s showing the notification for no reason at all. The only similarity to your issue is that I’ve noticed is that it happens more frequently after the MBP has been asleep and may not be actively connected to the network.

Comment: Hmm… similar but different then… BTW, this has been ongoing from El Capitan right to Big Sur, across all the Macs in the house - all using the same 365 structure as a business account through BT in the UK.

Comment: @Tetsujin I know. It happens on my mid-2012 MBP as well sometimes, which can’t be updated past Catalina, but I don’t really care about that MBP since I don’t use it much anymore anyway.  It seems much more prevalent on Monterey, which doesn’t really surprise me given the amount of bugs in that OS in general.

Comment: I confirm all discussed issues to happen periodically. Exchange and Google accounts. For a variety of MBPs, even on iPhone sometimes. What is really confusing, is that you can edit account settings via the system's settings and via Calendar's preferences. The later one has additional options and an "enable/disable" button. Maybe, toggling it off and on can explicitly trigger a popup with a password prompt.

Answer (score 3):

The solution described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/outlook/troubleshoot/sign-in/repeated-prompts-authentication) seems to help
Basically, it suggests going to the Key Chain and deleting certificates for `office`, `exchange`, and `Adal`.

Comment: That may help some, but that’s not the issue in my case.  It seems to just be some sort of background check that’s being attempted, and because WiFi disconnects after a while when the lid is closed, it loses the ability to actually complete this check.  Rather than being designed to simply timeout or say there was no connection, it was designed to say that the credentials are bad even when they aren’t.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, once the internet account opens, try clicking on the exchange account and then "details" (this usually prompts for the password again)

Comment: It doesn’t, and like I said already, the password it already has is correct and nothing actually stops working even though it asks.